# Where can i find the source code for the pfctl utility?

Tags: macos, firewall, open-source, pfctl

I have looked here: https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu

But all i can find is the 'back end' for the pfctl tool, but i am interested in the command-line pfctl tool itself, the option parser and so on.

Has Apple released source code for this or documented it in a manual page for 10.14.1?

Comment: Is the version of macOS you want this source listed here? https://opensource.apple.com/

Comment: @bmike yes (10.14.1) :) but i still can't find the source for pfctl CLI tool there...

Comment: Searching that site is a PITA and the tool might not even be open sourced. Have you checked bsd sources? That might get you a file name or header name to latch on to and confirm if it’s released by Apple or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A path name embedded in the `pfctl` executable on my Mojave system:

```
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/PacketFilter/PacketFilter-85/pfctl/pfctl_optimize.c
```

suggests that it's part of a "PacketFilter" package which Apple hasn't released.

However, this filename suggests that the tool is very similar (if not identical) to [the OpenBSD utility of the same name](https://github.com/openbsd/src/tree/master/sbin/pfctl).

Comment: Thanks! But i would have thought they'd be required by law to release it - as it's based on the openbsd pfctl code afaict

Comment: The BSD license doesn't require source to be released. You may be thinking of GPL, which is more common for Linux software.

Comment: ah, good point, you are correct! woe is me...